# Magento 2 - page.main.title below content

Tags: magento2, layout, template

the page main title is below the content.

You can see the problem in the picture.

[image]

> /magento/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/title.phtml
>
> Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title

How can I fix that?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this only Account pages please create `customer_account.xml` in you theme below path `Yourtheme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml` and add below line

```
<move element="page.main.title" destination="content.top" before="-"/>
```

If this issue in all pages then add below line in `Yourtheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`.

```
<move element="page.main.title" destination="content.top" before="-"/>
```

---

May be you have used below code in XML

```
<move element="page.main.title" destination="content" after="-"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basic html error

The page title must be written in the title tag
and any heading in the header tag.

refer to the example

Page Title

## Bold header

light header

To align the title in the center you can use 
style="text-align: center" in the   HTML.

Comment: can you describe the solution more detailled?